# value too large in quartz in jboss

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am getting following error in the server log. I would like to know which query(insert or update) making changes on the column of a quartz table.

```
 ERROR [org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX] MisfireHandler: Error
 handling misfires: Couldn't store trigger: ORA-01438: value larger
 than specified precision allowed for this column
 org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger: ORA-01438:
 value larger than specified precision allowed for this column  [See
 nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store
 trigger: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for
 this column  [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438:
 value larger than specified precision allowed for this column ]]   at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreTX.java:1354)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:2449)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:2468)
 * Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) --------------- org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger: ORA-01438:
 value larger than specified precision allowed for this column  [See
 nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438: value larger than
 specified precision allowed for this column ]  at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:964)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:780)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreTX.java:1352)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:2449)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:2468)
 * Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) --------------- java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified
 precision allowed for this column

    at
 oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)    at
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)  at
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)     at
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at
 oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
    at
 org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:365)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.updateSimpleTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1440)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:942)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:780)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreTX.java:1352)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:2449)
    at
 org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:2468)
```

Could you please any one help on this. Is there any configuration parameter to see the insert/update queries in the log?

Comment: Could you please any one answer my query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error due to the `TIMES_TRIGGERED` column in the `SIMPLE_TRIGGERS` table growing too large to be stored in the column, which is normally defined as NUMBER(7) (i.e. max value of 9999999).

Normally, you can just set this column to `0` and the error will go away (until the `TIMES_TRIGGERED` gets big enough again).  It seems like quartz looks at the start time of the trigger and the configured frequency and determines what the value should be and overrides your update, though in my experience it has set it to something well below the max.

See [Couldn't store trigger](http://quartz.10975.n7.nabble.com/Couldn-t-store-trigger-ORA-01438-value-larger-than-specified-precision-td8697.html) for more details.